# how to remove a value from an array in database using nodejs and mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to remove a value from an array in my database which I get from url.

I use the code below but I get nothing. It doesn't go to the `for` loop.

```
app.get('/remove/:medid/:tokenid', function(req, res) {
    var medid = req.params.medid;
    var token = req.params.tokenid;
    var query = { tokenid: token, mediaid !== 'undefined' && mediaid.length > 0 }

    user.find(query).exec(function(err, result) {

        if (err) {
            res.send('erooooooor')
        }
        if (!result) {
            res.send('whooops, you dont have any media yet :)')
        } else {
            console.log('its here')
            for (var i in result.mediaid) {
                console.log(i)
                if (i == medid) {
                    user.update({ tokenid: token }, { $pull: { mediaid: medid } }, function(err, result2) {
                        if (err) {
                            res.send('an error happened')
                        } else {
                            console.log('deleted')
                                //res.send('your tokenid  is '+ token)
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    res.send('media id didnt match')
                }
            }
        }

    });
});
```

My database has 3 objects **`userid` and `tokenid` which are strings and `mediaid` which is an array**.

Also, I want to check if my `mediaid` array is null or not and exist is this code

```
mediaid !== 'undefined' && mediaid.length > 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got your json syntax incorrect in following line

```
var query = {tokenid: token, mediaid !== 'undefined' && mediaid.length > 0}
```

You should probably just let your query be based on token id.

```
var query = {tokenid: token};
```

Also when you write `for(var i in  result.mediaid)`, for each iteration of loop, the variable 'i' is assigned the index of current element, not its value. So your if condition should be modified to check `result.mediaid[i] == medid` instead of `i == medid`. Modified loop should look something like:

```
for(var i in  result.mediaid){
    console.log(i);
    if(result.mediaid[i] === medid){
        user.update({tokenid: token}, {$pull: {mediaid: medid}},function(err, result2){
        if (err){
            res.send('an error happened');
        }
        else{
            console.log('deleted');
            //res.send('your tokenid  is '+ token)
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering me, but it makes no difference! u see that console.log(i) after for?? when i run it i doesnt appear in command prompt!!

Comment: then possibly no mediaid(s) have been saved in DB. If result.mediaid is an empty array, the loop won't be executed at all. You can verify this by querying your mongodb manually from a terminal.

Comment: no I checked. my database is ok. and if its empty doesnt it go to this part?      if(!result)??

Comment: Not really. if(!result) part will only be executed if result itself was not returned. You could may be extend that condition `if(!result || !result.mediaid || result.mediaid.length < 0)`, this should give you a better view of your result. You can also try printing the entire `result` variable for debugging.

Comment: oh thanks for this valuable information. i printed the result and its like this: [{_id: sth, userid: 'sth', mediaid: ['sth','sth2'], tokenid: 'sth'}].    why is it inside a bracket? and the result.mediaid is undefined?? what is going on?? sorry im a total beginer :)

Comment: Ahh, find() gives callback with array of matched results. If you are certain that there will only be one row for each `tokenid` you could use `findOne()` instead of `find()`. eg, `user.findOne(query).exec(function(err, result){` should return single object instead of array.

Comment: yes yes i got that, i have another problem, it stuck in the loop!! and do it over and over again! what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Please, you can replace to:

```
app.get('/remove/:mediaid/:tokenid', function(req, res){
var medid = req.params.mediaid;
var token = req.params.tokenid;
var query = {tokenid: token, mediaid !== 'undefined' && mediaid.length > 0}
```

UPDATED:

I recommended that print after `console.log(medid, token);`

I hoped help you - Jose Carlos Ramos

Comment: thanks but i cant see any changes? what did you change?

Comment: @ShahrzadA mediaid <=> medid

Comment: yeah i got that but still doesnt work!! it wont go to the for loop!!